# Opengl Renderbuffer Texture touchmove ios issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es, touch, eaglcontext

I am using OpenGL and using an example of GLPaint. I have created an app which applies twirl on image (texture) when the user touches the image. I have an issue that I need to save first touch and then apply next phase and so on. But on next touch the previous applied effect is removed.
I have tried to use depth buffer & frame buffer both, but have not been able to get the desired result. I am attaching all my code and shaders

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

#import "PaintingView.h"

enum {
    ATTRIB_VERTEX,
    NUM_ATTRIBS
};

@interface PaintingView()
{
    // The pixel dimensions of the backbuffer
    GLint backingWidth;
    GLint backingHeight;

    EAGLContext *context;

    // OpenGL names for the renderbuffer and framebuffers used to render to this view
    GLuint viewRenderbuffer, viewFramebuffer, texture;

    // OpenGL name for the depth buffer that is attached to viewFramebuffer, if it exists (0 if it does not exist)
    GLuint depthRenderbuffer;


    Boolean needsErase;

    // Shader objects
//    GLuint vertexShader;
//    GLuint fragmentShader;
//    GLuint shaderProgram;

    // Buffer Objects
    GLuint vboId;

    BOOL initialized;

    GLint inputImageTexture2Uniform, filterPositionAttribute, filterTextureCoordinateAttribute;

    NSString *vertexShader, *fragmentShader;

    Boolean firstTouch;

    CGPoint twirlCenter;
}

// Program Handle
@property (assign, nonatomic, readonly) GLuint program;

// Attribute Handles
@property (assign, nonatomic, readonly) GLuint aPosition;

@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint location;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint previousLocation;


@end

@implementation PaintingView

// Implement this to override the default layer class (which is [CALayer class]).
// We do this so that our view will be backed by a layer that is capable of OpenGL ES rendering.
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

// The GL view is stored in the nib file. When it's unarchived it's sent -initWithCoder:
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = NO;
        // In this application, we want to retain the EAGLDrawable contents after a call to presentRenderbuffer.
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

        //        context = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
            return nil;
        }

        // Set the view's scale factor as you wish
        self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

        // Make sure to start with a cleared buffer
        needsErase = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

// If our view is resized, we'll be asked to layout subviews.
// This is the perfect opportunity to also update the framebuffer so that it is
// the same size as our display area.
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = [self initGL];
    }
    else {
        [self resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    }
}

- (BOOL)initGL
{
    // Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    // This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
    // allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

    // For this sample, we do not need a depth buffer. If you do, this is how you can create one and attach it to the framebuffer:
    //    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    //    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
    //    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    //    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
        return NO;
    }

    // Setup the view port in Pixels
    glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object to hold our data
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

    // Load the brush texture
    //    brushTexture = [self textureFromName:@"transprnt.png"];

    // Load shaders
    [self setupShaders];

    inputImageTexture2Uniform = [self uniformIndex:@"inputImageTexture"];
    UIImage *uyet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kerala.jpg"];
    [self setImage:uyet];




    // Enable blending and set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    return YES;
}

- (void)setupShaders
{
    vertexShader = @"RWTBase";
    fragmentShader = @"TwirlShader";
    // Program
    _program = [self programWithVertexShader:vertexShader fragmentShader:fragmentShader];

    // Attributes
    filterPositionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "aPosition");
    filterTextureCoordinateAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "inputTextureCoordinate");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(filterPositionAttribute);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(filterTextureCoordinateAttribute);

    glBindAttribLocation(_program,
                         filterPositionAttribute,
                         [@"aPosition" UTF8String]);
    glBindAttribLocation(_program,
                         filterTextureCoordinateAttribute,
                         [@"inputTextureCoordinate" UTF8String]);



    // Program
    glUseProgram(_program);

    static const GLfloat textureCoordinates[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(filterPositionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(filterTextureCoordinateAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates);

}

- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{
    // Allocate color buffer backing based on the current layer size
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

    // For this sample, we do not need a depth buffer. If you do, this is how you can allocate depth buffer backing:
    //    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
    //    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    //    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer objectz %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
        return NO;
    }


    // Update viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    return YES;
}

// Releases resources when they are not longer needed.
- (void)dealloc
{
    // Destroy framebuffers and renderbuffers
    if (viewFramebuffer) {
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
        viewFramebuffer = 0;
    }
    if (viewRenderbuffer) {
        glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
        viewRenderbuffer = 0;
    }
    if (depthRenderbuffer)
    {
        glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        depthRenderbuffer = 0;
    }
    // vbo
    if (vboId) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboId);
        vboId = 0;
    }

    // tear down context
    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
}

// Custom Methods....
/*
 ***********
 *         *
 *   ATG   *
 *         *
 ***********
 */
#pragma mark - Compile & Link
- (GLuint)programWithVertexShader:(NSString*)vsh fragmentShader:(NSString*)fsh {
    // Build shaders
    GLuint vertexShader1 = [self shaderWithName:vsh type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
    GLuint fragmentShader1 = [self shaderWithName:fsh type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

    // Create program
    GLuint programHandle = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach shaders
    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader1);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader1);

    // Link program
    glLinkProgram(programHandle);

    // Check for errors
    GLint linkSuccess;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
    if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[1024];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"%@:- GLSL Program Error: %s", [self class], messages);
    }

    // Delete shaders
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader1);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader1);

    return programHandle;
}

- (GLuint)shaderWithName:(NSString*)name type:(GLenum)type {
    // Load the shader file
    NSString* file;
    if (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER) {
        file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"vsh"];
    } else if (type == GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) {
        file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"fsh"];
    }

    // Create the shader source
    const GLchar* source = (GLchar*)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];

    // Create the shader object
    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(type);

    // Load the shader source
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &source, 0);

    // Compile the shader
    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    // Check for errors
    GLint compileSuccess;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);
    if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"%@:- GLSL Shader Error: %s", [self class], messages);
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}

// Touch Methiods..
#pragma mark - Touches

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//    CGRect                bounds = [self.view bounds];
//    UITouch*            touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
//    //    NSLog(@"Hellossss");
//    firstTouch = YES;
//    _location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
//    _location.y = bounds.size.height - _location.y;
}

// Handles the continuation of a touch.
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGRect              bounds = [self bounds];
    UITouch*            touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];


    UITouch* touchEvent = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationInView = [touchEvent locationInView:self];
    twirlCenter = getNormalizedPoint(self, locationInView);


//    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
//    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    // Render the stroke
    [self applyEffect];

//    [self drawEffects];
    if (firstTouch) {
        firstTouch = NO;
        _previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        _previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - _previousLocation.y;
    } else {
        _location = [touch locationInView:self];
        _location.y = bounds.size.height - _location.y;
        _previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        _previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - _previousLocation.y;
    }

    // Render the stroke
    [self renderLineFromPoint:_previousLocation toPoint:_location];
}

-(void)drawEffects {
//    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
//    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    // Draw
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);

    glUseProgram(_program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


    // Display the buffer
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

-(void)applyEffect {

    //        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    //        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    GLint radiusIndex = [self uniformIndex:@"radius"];
    glUniform1f(radiusIndex, 0.1);

    GLint angleIndex = [self uniformIndex:@"angle"];
    glUniform1f(angleIndex, -0.5);

    //    twirlCenter = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
    GLint centerIndex = [self uniformIndex:@"center"];

    GLfloat positionArray[2];
    positionArray[0] = twirlCenter.x;
    positionArray[1] = twirlCenter.y;
    glUniform2fv(centerIndex, 1, positionArray);

}

// Drawings a line onscreen based on where the user touches
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
    static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
    NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
    count,
    i;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    start.x *= scale;
    start.y *= scale;
    end.x *= scale;
    end.y *= scale;

    // Allocate vertex array buffer
    if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
        vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
    count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / 3), 1);
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
            vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
            vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }

        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexCount += 1;
    }

    // Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Draw
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glUseProgram(_program);


    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);

    // Display the buffer
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

///fsdffdf


static CGPoint getNormalizedPoint(UIView* view, CGPoint locationInView)
{
    const float normalizedX = (locationInView.x / view.bounds.size.width) * (2.f - 1.f);
    const float normalizedY = ((view.bounds.size.height - locationInView.y) / view.bounds.size.height) * (2.f - 1.f);

    return CGPointMake(normalizedX, normalizedY);
}

// set Img...

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Create an RGBA bitmap context
    CGImageRef CGImage = image.CGImage;
    GLint width = (GLint)CGImageGetWidth(CGImage);
    GLint height = (GLint)CGImageGetHeight(CGImage);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = width * 4;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    // Invert vertically for OpenGL
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context1, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context1, 1, -1);
    CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), CGImage);
    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context1);

    //    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
    //    [self _setTextureData:textureData width:width height:height];
    [self generateDefaultTextureWithWidth:width height:height data:textureData];

    CGContextRelease(context1);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}

- (GLuint)generateDefaultTextureWithWidth:(GLint)width height:(GLint)height data:(GLvoid *)data
{
    //    texture = 0;
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(inputImageTexture2Uniform, 0);


    //    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    //    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    //    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return texture;
}

- (GLuint)uniformIndex:(NSString *)uniformName
{
    return glGetUniformLocation(_program, [uniformName UTF8String]);
}

- (void)setPaintLine12
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawEffects) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

// Erases the screen
- (void)erase
{
    NSLog(@"erase");
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Also attaching shader as follows:

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

uniform vec2 center;
uniform float radius;
uniform float angle;

void main()
{
    vec2 textureCoordinateToUse = textureCoordinate;
    float dist = distance(center, textureCoordinate);
    if (dist < radius)
    {
        textureCoordinateToUse -= center;
        float percent = (radius - dist) / radius;
        float theta = percent * percent * angle * 8.0;
        float s = sin(theta);
        float c = cos(theta);
        textureCoordinateToUse = vec2(dot(textureCoordinateToUse, vec2(c, -s)), dot(textureCoordinateToUse, vec2(s, c)));
        textureCoordinateToUse += center;
    }

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinateToUse );
}
```

Please help me to debug what is wrong and how to resolve this.

You can also run complete project from here [Twirl on Touch-github](https://github.com/niralipandey/Twirl-on-touch)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be redrawing the whole screen on touch which then overwrites the pixels previously modified with the original image. You also have other issues such as the effect ratio seems to equal to your screen ratio and is not constant between devices.

Anyway to keep the effect you will need to continue working on the same image (texture) without overwriting the whole screen. This specific effect may be a bit tricky to make it nice but generally you have 3 options:

1. You can update only the part of the screen effected by the touch. That means creating a vertex data where positions represent a rectangle around the touched point and the texture coordinates representing the part of the texture you need to redraw. The downside of this procedure this it will overwrite the previous effect if the positions are overlapping.
2. You keep adding the effects on the same texture by having a texture bound to the FBO (frame buffer object). Now the FBO is a target you draw to as well as its texture is a source. Once redrawn you will need to then draw the texture to your main frame buffer. It might be you will also need double buffering to achieve this correctly (have 2 same textures where first is a source, second a destination). The downside is the effects will stack if placed on the same position.
3. Save all the touches and create a system which will create the effects on all the touch location at the same time. This means you will need to restructure your shader input to handle this somehow. Probably the best solution would be to create a FBO which will hold your mapping data on which you can then control how the effects are stacked. The mapping texture may then contain something like an angle and radius for every pixel. The on every refresh you pass the mapping texture and the original texture to the texture which will use the mapping to find the correct pixel and redraw the whole scene in 1 draw call. The down side is this is a lot of work.

Comment: Do you have any example or sample code, which I can use as reference. As I am not expert in opengl so looking hard to understand this.

Comment: What part? The first is very simple, all you need to do is a little bit of math to convert the view coordinates to the GL coordinates. The second one requires a FBO which is still pretty simple and can find tons on web, after you have it all is the same as with your primary frame buffer. The third one requires a lot of math and logic to create and process the mapping otherwise pretty much the same as the second.

Comment: Second one. i am not able to find example for FBO.

Comment: Using Framebuffer Objects to Render to a Texture:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html

Comment: I was trying to apply this concept but not able to successfully achieve this. Do you have any sample code, so can do this. Or if you can change in few lines in my existing code and make this working. I tried but end with nothing working as needed.